# Python: Alternative to list of "if" conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a more elegant alternative of multiple "if" conditions in fewer lines of code. The majority of this conditions are quite simple, as seen in the example:

```
        if status == 'young':
            i = 1
        elif status == 'middle age':
            i = 3
        elif status == 'elder':
            i = 4
        elif status == 'baby':
            i = 5
        elif status == 'deceased':
            i = 6
```

I would like to make something like:

```
if status == 'young', 'mid age', 'elder'...
   i = 1, 3, 4...
```

Is it possible in python??

Comment: use a dictionary. dictionaries are hashtables and they are good for lookup

Answer (score 11):

Use a dictionary

```
statuses = {'young': 1, 'middle age': 3}
i = statuses.get(status)
```

Comment: And if you need to simulate an `else`, the second argument to `.get` is the default to return if the key is not in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list and `list.index()`, in this way:

```
statuses = ['young', 'middle age', 'elder'...]
try:
    i = statuses.index(status)+1
except:
    print("Status not in list of statuses!")
```

Working:
First, a list of statuses is created. Then, to get the index of the `status` in the list, `statuses.index(status)` is used. This returns the index of `status` from the list `statuses`. Now, as lists are indexed from *0*, we need to do `statuses.index(status)+1`.
The `try-except` is used as if the `status` is not in `statuses`, the `index()` function will raise an error.

Comment: Note: mid-age is index 3, not 2. Also, this worth pointing out this incurs a linear runtime, compared to constant with a dictionary or if statements

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I completely agree, but this method allows for fewer *lines of code*, and this (linear runtime) does not matter much if the search is going to take place only once-or-twice, but this method must be avoided if this is needed for 1000s or more times in a single run.